# How can I have this table with the correct figures from this data here?

Tags: pandas

How do I end up with this?

[image: outcome]

From this kind of data

[image: data]

What I did gave me a wrong answer

```
       A  A-  B  B+  B-  C  C+  C-  D  D+  D-  E  X  TOT
AGR    0   0  0   1   0  0   1   1  0   0   1  0  0    4
H/SC   0   0  1   0   0  1   0   0  0   0   2  0  0    4
CRE    0   0  0   1   0  0   0   1  1   1   0  0  0    4
GEO    0   0  1   0   0  0   1   0  0   0   2  0  0    4
CRE    0   0  0   0   0  0   0   0  0   0   2  0  0    2
```

My code

```
columns = ["A",'A-','B+',"B",'B-','C+',"C",'C-','D+',"D",'D-',"E",'X']
            sub_lists = list(df1[column_list])
            sub_lists = pd.Series(sub_lists)
            #print(sub_lists)
            agr = (pd.crosstab(sub_lists, df1['AGR'], margins=True,       margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
            cre = (pd.crosstab(sub_lists, df1['CRE'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
            geo = (pd.crosstab(sub_lists, df1['GEO'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
            hsc = (pd.crosstab(sub_lists, df1['H/SC'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
            bst = (pd.crosstab(sub_lists, df1['BST'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))

            c = pd.concat([agr, cre,geo,hsc,bst], axis=1, join='inner')
            d = c.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
            d['TOT'] = d[columns].sum(axis=1)

STREAM  ADM NAME    KCPE    GEO CRE H/SC    AGR BST
EAGLE   231 MITCHEL     279 D   D+  E   D-  B
EAGLE   322 BEATRICE 268    E   C-  E   D+  C
HAWK    654 BERYL   344 A   C-  E   A-  C
EAGLE   335 SOFI    266 E   C-  E   D   C
HAWK    321 LOICE   319 E   D+  C-  B   A-
```

HAWK    234 BETTY   284 E   D-

Comment: Is possible text version of input data?

Comment: Edited with the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is changed by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for 2 columns `DataFrame`, then is used [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with changed `iloc` for `.iloc[:-1]` for remove last row, not last column, [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing categories and last for remove index and columns names (`variable`,`value`) by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
columns = ["A",'A-','B+',"B",'B-','C+',"C",'C-','D+',"D",'D-',"E",'X']

cols = ['AGR','CRE','GEO','H/SC','BST']
df1 = df[cols].melt()

df2 = (pd.crosstab(df1['variable'], df1['value'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL')
        .iloc[:-1]
        .reindex(columns + ['TOTAL'], fill_value=0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df2)
      A  A-  B+  B  B-  C+  C  C-  D+  D  D-  E  X  TOTAL
AGR   0   1   0  1   0   0  0   0   1  2   1  0  0      6
BST   0   2   0  1   0   0  3   0   0  0   0  0  0      6
CRE   0   0   0  0   0   0  0   3   2  0   1  0  0      6
GEO   1   0   0  0   0   0  0   0   0  1   0  4  0      6
H/SC  0   0   0  0   0   0  0   1   0  0   0  5  0      6
```

Comment: You've made it look so simple. Are you one of those who created pandas?

Comment: And can I have the words variable and value removed from the table?

Comment: @Ptar - No, pandas developers are obviously really busy and no time for answering.